# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.number')

Tags: react-native

After installing react-native-md-textinput when i tried to start the app getting the following error.
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'React.PropTypes.Number')
underline.js

Below is my package.json

"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.49.5",
"react-native-md-textinput": "^2.0.4",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.19"

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**Step 1: install prop-types dependency**

```
npm/yarn install prop-types create-react-class
```

**Step 2: Add the following to node_modules/react/index.js**

```
module.exports.PropTypes = require('prop-types');
let createClass;
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'createClass', {
  get: function() {
    if (!createClass) {
      createClass = require('create-react-class').bind(module.exports);
    }
    return createClass;
  }
});
```

ref: https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/328

Comment: I am facing the same issue even after using import PropTypes from 'prop-types';"  can anyone help?

Comment: You also need to update `React.PropTypes` to just `PropTypes` throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by importing `PropTypes from 'prop-types'` instead of `'react'`

```
import React, {Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```